# TSError cannot find module when importing my TS library

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I built a TypeScript library containing models and API calls for multiple web apps that will use the same backend.

I want to export my models and functions in modules, and be able in the consumer apps to do:

```
import { SomeType, SomeFunction } from 'myLib/myModule';
```

Currently it works fine, but I have the following TSError:
TS2307: Cannot find module 'myLib/myModule' or its corresponding type declarations.

I'm building the library with Vite and I use it in my consumer apps as a .tgz file.

Here is the file architecture of the library. The index.ts in api/ and computation/ are exporting all the models and services contained in the sub directories:

[image]

And the index.ts located in src/ does:

```
export * from './api';
export * from './computation';
```

The init.ts file simply exports a function to initialize the library.

I also have the following configuration files:
tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "coanda-sdk-ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "files": ["dist"],
  "main": "./dist/coanda-sdk-ts.cjs.js",
  "module": "./dist/coanda-sdk-ts.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/coanda-sdk-ts.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/coanda-sdk-ts.cjs.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./api": {
      "import": "./dist/api/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/api/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/api/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./computation": {
      "import": "./dist/computation/index.js",
      "require": "./dist/computation/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/computation/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./init": {
      "import": "./dist/init.js",
      "require": "./dist/init.js",
      "types": "./dist/init.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build && tsc --project tsconfig.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
}
```

And vite.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const { defineConfig } = require('vite');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  resolve: {},
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: {
        api: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/api/index.ts'),
        computation: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/computation/index.ts'),
        init: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/init.ts')
      },
      name: 'coanda-sdk-ts',
      fileName: (format) => `coanda-sdk-ts.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {},
  },
});
```

With coanda-sdk-ts the name of my library.

And finally, here is a picture of my dist/ folder after building the library:
[image]

**I guess those files have something to do with my problem, this looks strange:**

```
src/coanda-sdk-ts.cjs.js
src/coanda-sdk-ts.cjs2.js
src/coanda-sdk-ts.cjs3.js
src/coanda-sdk-ts.es.js
src/coanda-sdk-ts.es2.js
src/coanda-sdk-ts.es3.js
```

I feel like I've tried so many things in order to remove the TSError, maybe the configs don't make any sense anymore, but I'm totally unable to find what's wrong here.
The consumer app works and uses the functions provided by the library correctly, by importing the modules like so, for example:

```
import { SomeAPIFunction } from 'coanda-sdk-ts/api';
```

And I'd really like not to change that, if possible. Can someone please help me?

Comment: src in your module specifiers isn't correct. TypeScript doesn't perform any translation on module specifiers, it outputs them verbatim.

Comment: @Aluan Haddad
Thank you so much for your time! I'm not sure I understood what you meant because I'm totally new to this, but there is no occurence of 'src' in my modules. I mean, I'm not trying to import from 'src', I'm only using relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some more things, such as removing Vite (because I didn't really need it after all), my boss came out with the solution. So I'm sharing it, in case someone were stuck on the same thing.

I had to add the following in my library's package.json:

```
 "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "api": [ "./dist/api/index.d.ts" ],
      "computation": [ "./dist/computation/index.d.ts" ],
      "init": [ "./dist/init.d.ts" ]
    }
  }
```

And now the imports are properly resolved without TSErrors.
Thank you all for reading!